# How to decode &#39; in c#

Tags: c#

I found a similar question on how to decode `^#39;` or simply `'` in php, but I have been having trouble finding a way of decoding that value in c#.  Thoughts?  I have been trying the following in my code...

```
   agenda.MeetingLocation = agenda.MeetingLocation.Replace("'", "''")
```

However, the value in my form field is John Doe's test.  The value I see for `agenda.MeetingLocation` is:

> John Doe's test

(the ^ is a &)

Comment: If you're seeing HTML-encoded values in your server code, your problem probably lies elsewhere - you shouldn't have to deal with that in C#, so see if you're double-encoding something somewhere that you shouldn't be.

Comment: Do you have `^#39` or `&#39`?

Comment: &#39.  I apologize for the confusion

Comment: @CBC_NS consider updating your post with `&#39` - that `^#39` is very strange looking... Use back quote to escape the values if needed.

Answer (score 4):

This should work if it's encoded like "& #39;" instead of "^#39;". Are you sure your input uses "^"?

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("John Doe&#39;s test.");
```